# Set view order with code in a listview using ListViewXml.OrderBy

Tags: development, list-view, ordering

So I have this line: lvwp.ListViewXml.OrderBy.. - after this I have no Idea what to write?

I would like to assign something like:

Combining like this:

```
lvwp.ListViewXml.OrderBy<FieldRef Name='Index' Ascending='TRUE' />();
```

will ofcourse not work

I have looked at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx , but I just dont get it, Im pretty new with programming and dont really understand concepts like Enumerable and generics

Anyway, is there a simple answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

`ListViewXml` is of type `string`, so you should not use Linq at all on it.

It should be set with a string containing [CAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd588092%28office.11%29.aspx)

Something like this:

```
lvwp.ListViewXml = "<Query><Where>YOUR FILTER CAML IF NEEDED</Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Index' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy><Query>"
```